# Show and hide switch in C# database applications

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a small one line application and recently I have been instruct to remove all persons form it.  That is I have several fields and one of it is a owner field.  I am not going to move the owners from the database but only hide them and I need to be able to show some fields again when I will be contacted by that person saying: "You can show my name". This is an Visual Studio application with underlying SQL database. My dream solution would be a switch that make this name field true or false so I will be able to show only those name which I am allowed to show with a click of a button.

What do you think would be the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: This isn't related to sql-server or visual-studio and only posibly to c#. What you must do is change your visualization layer (UI=user interface) and you should also change your data definition (DAL=data access layer) to not pull the data. You have supplied no information on what UI and DAL technologies you are using and no code of what you are doing so far, so this question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, since you didn't specify what type of C# application you have (ASP.NET C#, WinForms, WCF, WPF), I'll assume you mean either Winforms or WPF. The easiest way is a checkbox, and then on change, hide or show the other fields that you want to hide. Then do your database calls. That's all I can give you without more info.

Comment: Thanks - this is an ASP.NET Application.  I like you idea - now I am going to try implement.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that. One way is to introduce an extra bit field/column in your ‘User’ (or whatever it is) database table that would represent whether to show or hide a user name. Based on this field you would show or hide the user name within your application. This could be checked/unchecked directly in your database (by you), or via an application UI. You could implement ‘Admin’ page/view/form that would be dedicated to admins (you) that would have enough privileges to update the above specified column.